# Ignore Certain Properties when Deserializing Json String

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How do I ignore certain properties when deserializing a json string.

Say I have a string

```
{"Id": 123, "name":"Test", "Description":"desc123ds"}
```

and a class with the same properties.
In some cases I don't want to return "Id".

I have tried a custom ContractResolver but the only thing it does is sets the default value and the property remains present in the json string.

```
public class CoreJsonContractResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver
    {
        public static CoreJsonContractResolver<T> Instance { get; } = new CoreJsonContractResolver<T>();

        protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
        {
            var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
            if(property.DeclaringType == typeof(T))
            {
                if (property.PropertyName == "Id")
                    property.Ignored = true;
            }
            return property;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: 
The reason why I didn't use [JsonIgnore] property is because I need to ignore properties only in certain cases.

Comment: "In some cases I don't want to return "Id"". How is returning data related to deserializing data? If you don't want to return that data, use a DTO/ViewModel that doesn't have it, don't hack around the serialization process

Comment: You say "the property remains present in the json string." which I find a bit confusing. Are you trying to not deserialize the ID property, or are you trying to remove it from the source json string ?

In the former case, it seems what your code is doing is the right thing. Leaving the Id property on your class at its' default value...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `JsonIgnore` [attribure](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) and have a look at this [article](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size)

Comment: improve the comment and make it and aswer

Comment: I have edited the question. Don't need it to be always ignored, only in some cases.